# Upfront lump sum payment vs Monthly interest-free instalments

Tags: taxes

I have a debt of $1000 and have the option of paying it upfront or pay in 12 equal interest-free instalments.

Can someone calculate the Future Value difference between the 2, assuming banks are giving me interest rate at 3.0% APY?

It definitely makes more sense to pay in instalments since it's interest-free, but I want to know how much difference there is at the end of 12 months. Is it just the added interest component of $13+ or is it more appropriate that I need to double that since there's inflation?

Not sure why I keep thinking that the appropriate amount should be double that.

[cashflow calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN9jy.jpg)

Comment: sometimes with these types of deals there is a penalty if you miss a payment, so that any savings will disappear if you miss it by one day.

Comment: Your calculations are wrong. You need to calculate future value of $1000 as well. That would be $1000 + 30% = $1030. The correct cash flow difference of future values of the two will be $16.13.

Comment: Depending on the terms of the deal, the _risk_ is if you miss a payment, you get charged ALL of the back interest, usually as significantly higher rates. So only do it if you are ABSOLUTELY SURE you can make each payment on time.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the debt is due to $1000 in the bank, from which a repayment `p` can be taken at the end of each month for 12 months.

```
p = 1000/12
```

Calculating the balance at the end of the first month `a[1]`, based on $1000, `s`, at monthly rate `r` (from the APY effective rate), less repayment `p`.

```
s = 1000
r = (1 + 0.03)^(1/12) - 1
a[1] = s (1 + r) - p
```

Balances at the end of the second and third months are

```
a[2] = a[1] (1 + r) - p
a[3] = a[2] (1 + r) - p
```

In general `a[n] = (p + (1 + r)^n (r s - p))/r`

```
a[12] = 16.3234
```

$16.32 would be gained by making the monthly repayments compared to repaying the $1000 debt from the bank immediately, for no gain or loss.

---

The same via Excel

```
=FV((1 + 0.03)^(1/12) - 1, 12, 1000/12, -1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making it a lot complicated. And you missed to calculate the future value of $1000.

The easiest way to do this job is to simply use Excel to calculate future value of given cash flows. There is an [in-built function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fv-function-2eef9f44-a084-4c61-bdd8-4fe4bb1b71b3#:%7E:text=FV%2C%20one%20of%20the%20financial,of%20a%20series%20of%20payments.) for calculating future value.

---

**To calculate FV of 12 monthly instalments of $83.333 at *3% rate per annum* or *0.25% per month*, use the following formula:**
`= FV(0.25%, 12, 83.333)`

This will return `-1,013.86`, with negative sign denoting cash outflow.

---

**Now to calculate FV of lumpsum money of $1000 at 3% rate per annum, use the same formula:**
`=FV(3%, 1, 1000, , 1)`.

This will return `-1,030.00`.

---

You should opt for first choice as it involves less cash outflow of $16.13.